# How to save Sql Image retrieved through web service on IOS Sqllite database

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I have a sql table on server. I want to get whole table content to IOS sqllite database. Everything works fine except the SQL Server Image data type. I make a call to WCF web service in order to get table data to IOS and save the data in SQLLite database to an entity that has the same columns as my sql server table.

I use Image type in Sql Server, but on IOS I used Binary Data type for the image when I was creating the entity. I use the following code in order to save the data to sqllite. I made sure I receive the data correctly. Somehow calling tbl setValue:forKey with received Sql Image data is not set. When I check it is nil. Does anybody know what I do wrong?

```
(NSManagedObject *) tblRow \\ this is my dictionary and when i call save, its contents are written to sqllite.

[tblRow setValue:(NSData *)[rowData GetValue:(NSString *)[ keys objectAtIndex:i]] forKey:[(NSString *) [keys objectAtIndex:i] lowerCaseString]];

[[Globals GetContext] save:&error]; // This save the data to sqllite
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory you are not doing anything wrong, so try to get the key and value before you pass then on `setValue:forKey:`, and check if they already exists.

```
NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
NSData *data = [rowData GetValue:key];
```

However, I recommend setting the property directly instead of using `setValue:forKey:` in this case, and further, it's much better to save the images on disk, and persist the respective paths on CoreData (assuming you are using it based on the classes and methods on your sample code).

Comment: I don't see how this is different than what I already have. Setting the value doesn't set the value. When I check, it's nil after the call to set value.

Comment: This is only to help you debuging and finding where's the mistake, like an invalid key or anything else. What kind of class is `tblRow`? You cast it to `NSManagedObject` but says it's a dictionary. Is there any error being printed on debugger? I think you have `tblRow == nil`, `data == nil` or an invalid `key`. Again, check all this. About using properties, it's a best practice.

Comment: I made sure data and key are populated, but when I call setValue:ForKey: on my entity object, I get nil for image data. My column's name is data, do you think that might be the reason?

Comment: Doing `tblRow.data = data;` doesn't work? Are you setting any other value to `tblRow` with success? Do you check this assignment with `NSLog` or via `po` on debugger? Can you post the response of your web service? Sorry about doing too many questions, it's just to figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I am not the one writing the WCF Service that sends me the image data and I learned that the service applies base 64 encoding to the data and setting base 64 string to NSData object and trying to save it was failing. Once I decoded the data, everything worked fine.